# Can't keep section header and table in the same page even after place identifier

Tags: tables

Table always shows up in the next page after section no matter how much smaller I make the table with `adjustbox` or I even when I use `\begin{table}[!ht]`. How can I keep the table and section in the same page?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[document,margin=2.5cm, top = 0.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\title{CSE Dataset Information}
\author{ }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Dataset Information}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{lscape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
N      & TaskType                  & N\_Class & K  & P  & max\_cardinality & mean\_cardinality & sum\_cardinality \\ \hline
48790  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 9  & 6  & 41               & 11.22             & 101              \\
32769  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 10 & 0  & 7518             & 1562.8            & 15628            \\
39926  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 5  & 4  & 22381            & 13495.6           & 67478            \\
10108  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 71 & 0  & 129              & 8.3               & 589              \\
72983  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 13 & 20 & 1063             & 167.46            & 2177             \\
8124   & Binary Classification     & 2        & 22 & 0  & 12               & 5.36              & 118              \\
891    & Binary Classification     & 2        & 6  & 5  & 838              & 278.83            & 1673             \\
73354  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 6  & 0  & 4362             & 1432.33           & 8594             \\
1728   & Multiclass Classification & 4        & 7  & 0  & 4                & 3.57              & 25               \\
12960  & Multiclass Classification & 5        & 9  & 0  & 5                & 3.56              & 32               \\
736    & Multiclass Classification & 5        & 6  & 14 & 27               & 13.67             & 82               \\
4331   & Multiclass Classification & 4        & 3  & 5  & 14               & 8.33              & 25               \\
20640  & Regression                & 0        & 1  & 9  & 5                & 5                 & 5                \\
163065 & Regression                & 0        & 5  & 2  & 3201             & 1127              & 5635             \\
2930   & Regression                & 0        & 46 & 35 & 28               & 6.91              & 318              \\
18249  & Regression                & 0        & 2  & 12 & 54               & 28                & 56              
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Description of Datasets}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{landscape}` will always start a new page also avoid scaling tables `begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}` will produce inconsisent font sizes)

Comment: Off-topic: `document` is not an option recognized by the `geometry` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what else can I use instead of landscape to rotate my table?

Comment: @Mico should I change ```document``` to something else

Comment: Sadly, 'm a extraordinarily poor mind reader. Truly sorry. I thus have no idea what you might have had in mind when you specified `document` as an option.

Comment: @Mico did not have a purpose when I set to ```document``` I was asking if you have any recommendation like changing it to ```a4```

Comment: You could use `\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular.....` but I doubt that you really need to rotate this. It could be formatted in portrait mode

Comment: you just need `\begin{table}[!hbtp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllll@{}}` No rotation or scaling.

Comment: Since I have no idea as to whether you intend to print your document on either "A4" or "US Letter" paper, I'm not in a position to recommend either `a4paper` or `letterpaper` as an option for the `geometry` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Your hunch that the table will fit in portrait mode is spot-on.

Answer (score 3):

Your table fits nicely in the margins, provided you group the “cardinality“ information.

I chose to print the figures right aligned (or aligned at the decimal point in one column) because this is how numbers are expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=2.5cm,
  top=0.5cm
]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\title{CSE Dataset Information}
\author{ }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Dataset Information}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  r
  l
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=5.2]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{N} &
TaskType &
{N\_Class} &
{K} &
{P} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{cardinality} \\
\cmidrule{6-8}
&&&&& max & {mean} & sum \\
\midrule
 48790 & Binary Classification     & 2 &  9 &  6 &    41 &    11.22 &   101 \\
 32769 & Binary Classification     & 2 & 10 &  0 &  7518 &  1562.8  & 15628 \\
 39926 & Binary Classification     & 2 &  5 &  4 & 22381 & 13495.6  & 67478 \\
 10108 & Binary Classification     & 2 & 71 &  0 &   129 &     8.3  &   589 \\
 72983 & Binary Classification     & 2 & 13 & 20 &  1063 &   167.46 &  2177 \\
  8124 & Binary Classification     & 2 & 22 &  0 &    12 &     5.36 &   118 \\
   891 & Binary Classification     & 2 &  6 &  5 &   838 &   278.83 &  1673 \\
 73354 & Binary Classification     & 2 &  6 &  0 &  4362 &  1432.33 &  8594 \\
  1728 & Multiclass Classification & 4 &  7 &  0 &     4 &     3.57 &    25 \\
 12960 & Multiclass Classification & 5 &  9 &  0 &     5 &     3.56 &    32 \\
   736 & Multiclass Classification & 5 &  6 & 14 &    27 &    13.67 &    82 \\
  4331 & Multiclass Classification & 4 &  3 &  5 &    14 &     8.33 &    25 \\
 20640 & Regression                & 0 &  1 &  9 &     5 &     5    &     5 \\
163065 & Regression                & 0 &  5 &  2 &  3201 &  1127    &  5635 \\
  2930 & Regression                & 0 & 46 & 35 &    28 &     6.91 &   318 \\
 18249 & Regression                & 0 &  2 & 12 &    54 &    28    &    56 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @eggreg The original data has more columns for which landscape seems a better way to format it. Could you add how to put landscape and title in the same page too?

Comment: @moli -- How many more columns?

Comment: @Mico 3 columns more, even though it seems like it can still fit portrait, I'd prefer lanscape

Comment: @moli - *You* may well prefer to typset the table in landscape mode. However, most readers -- including, in all likelihood, most readers of your papers -- do *not* like having to crane their necks 90 degrees just to gawk at a table that is typeset in landscape mode. They will thus very much appreciate you making an effort to make the table fit in portrait mode.

Comment: @Mico they don't have to crane their necks 90 degrees they can just rotate the paper

Answer (score 2):

I can see no compelling reason for rendering this table in landscape orientation. If you provide just a bit more structure in the header and cut out some of the rendundancies, the table will fit easily in ordinary, i.e., "portrait" orientation. For sure, there's no need for the `adjustbox` crutch.

To make the table a bit more readable, I'd align the numbers in the data columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers. Providing a bit of whitespace after every fourth row will also increase readability.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry} % set as needed
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\section*{Dataset Information}

\begin{table}[!hbt]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} T{6} l c T{2} T{2} T{5} T{5.2} T{5} @{}}
\toprule
{$N$} & Task Type & $N$\_Class & {$K$} & {$P$} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Cardinality} \\
\cmidrule(l){6-8}
&&&&& {max} & {mean} & {sum} \\ 
\midrule
48790  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 9  & 6  & 41               & 11.22             & 101              \\
32769  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 10 & 0  & 7518             & 1562.8            & 15628            \\
39926  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 5  & 4  & 22381            & 13495.6           & 67478            \\
10108  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 71 & 0  & 129              & 8.3               & 589              \\ 
\addlinespace
72983  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 13 & 20 & 1063             & 167.46            & 2177             \\
8124   & Binary Classification     & 2        & 22 & 0  & 12               & 5.36              & 118              \\
891    & Binary Classification     & 2        & 6  & 5  & 838              & 278.83            & 1673             \\
73354  & Binary Classification     & 2        & 6  & 0  & 4362             & 1432.33           & 8594             \\ 
\addlinespace
1728   & Multiclass Classification & 4        & 7  & 0  & 4                & 3.57              & 25               \\
12960  & Multiclass Classification & 5        & 9  & 0  & 5                & 3.56              & 32               \\
736    & Multiclass Classification & 5        & 6  & 14 & 27               & 13.67             & 82               \\
4331   & Multiclass Classification & 4        & 3  & 5  & 14               & 8.33              & 25               \\ 
\addlinespace
20640  & Regression                & 0        & 1  & 9  & 5                & 5                 & 5                \\
163065 & Regression                & 0        & 5  & 2  & 3201             & 1127              & 5635             \\
2930   & Regression                & 0        & 46 & 35 & 28               & 6.91              & 318              \\
18249  & Regression                & 0        & 2  & 12 & 54               & 28                & 56               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description of Datasets}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `\rotatebox{90}{<definition of tabular>}` if I wanted to keep that table, vertically.

However, the width can be reduced. For instance, I removed redundant word *Cardinality* and moved it to annotations at the bottom of the table. The numbers can also be formatted via `siunitx`. The table fits horizontally within the page when putting everything together. See the example.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,top=0.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}                         % Predefined rules
\usepackage{siunitx}                          % Extended number alignments

\newcommand\st[1]{#1\rlap{\textsuperscript{*}}}   % For annotation
\newcommand\sst[1]{#1\rlap{\textsuperscript{**}}}   % For annotation


\title{CSE Dataset Information}
\author{ }
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Dataset Information}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \centering
    \caption{Description of Datasets}\label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
            @{\hspace{6pt}} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            S[table-format=6, table-number-alignment=right]
            l
            *3{c}
            S[table-format=5]
            S[table-format=5.2]
            S[table-format=5]
            @{\hspace{6pt}}
        }
        \toprule
        {N} &
        {\st{Task Type}} &
        {N\_Class} &
        {K} &
        {P} &
        {\sst{Max}} &
        {\sst{Mean}} &
        {\sst{Sum}} \\
        \midrule
        48790  & Binary      & 2        & 9  & 6  & 41               & 11.22             & 101              \\
        32769  & Binary       & 2        & 10 & 0  & 7518             & 1562.8            & 15628            \\
        39926  & Binary       & 2        & 5  & 4  & 22381            & 13495.6           & 67478            \\
        10108  & Binary       & 2        & 71 & 0  & 129              & 8.3               & 589              \\
        72983  & Binary       & 2        & 13 & 20 & 1063             & 167.46            & 2177             \\
        8124   & Binary       & 2        & 22 & 0  & 12               & 5.36              & 118              \\
        891    & Binary       & 2        & 6  & 5  & 838              & 278.83            & 1673             \\
        73354  & Binary       & 2        & 6  & 0  & 4362             & 1432.33           & 8594             \\
        1728   & Multiclass   & 4        & 7  & 0  & 4                & 3.57              & 25               \\
        12960  & Multiclass   & 5        & 9  & 0  & 5                & 3.56              & 32               \\
        736    & Multiclass   & 5        & 6  & 14 & 27               & 13.67             & 82               \\
        4331   & Multiclass   & 4        & 3  & 5  & 14               & 8.33              & 25               \\
        20640  & Regression   & 0        & 1  & 9  & 5                & 5                 & 5                \\
        163065 & Regression   & 0        & 5  & 2  & 3201             & 1127              & 5635             \\
        2930   & Regression   & 0        & 46 & 35 & 28               & 6.91              & 318              \\
        18249  & Regression   & 0        & 2  & 12 & 54               & 28                & 56 \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{%
            \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}%
            \hspace{6pt}\textsuperscript{*} Classification,
            \hspace{6pt}\textsuperscript{**} Cardinarity}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]